# Generating new variable using across failed

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to mutate new variables using `across`, however it failed.

The raw data.frame `raw_df`:

```
library(tidyverse)
raw_df <- data.frame(region=c('R_1','R_2','R_3'),
                     qty_A=c(1,2,3),
                     qty_B=c(4,1,3),
                     qty_C=c(7,1,6),
                     qty_D=c(7,1,6),
                     price_A=c(100,110,300),
                     price_B=c(300,100,230),
                     price_C=c(170,116,66),
                     price_D=c(73,11,15))
```

below code can create new variables `amount_A/B/C` ,but not that smart

```
   raw_df %>% mutate(amount_A = qty_A * price_A,
                      amount_B = qty_B * price_B,
                      amount_C = qty_C * price_C,
                      amount_D = qty_D * price_D)
```

I want to use below code to replace previous one but failed, anyone can help on this ?
if there is no match qty and price, the result should be NULL

```
 raw_df %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric),
                             str_c('qty_',c('A','B','C')) * str_c('price_',c('A','B','C')),
                             .names = str_c('amount_',c('A','B','C'))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

raw_df <- raw_df |> 
  mutate(across(starts_with("qty_"), ~ . * get(str_replace(cur_column(), "qty_", "price_")), .names = "amount_{.col}")) |> 
  rename_with(~ str_replace(., "amount_qty", "amount"), starts_with("amount_qty"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `across` twice like so. Use the `.names` argument with [`glue`](https://glue.tidyverse.org/#usage) syntax to create your column names.

```r
library(dplyr)
raw_df %>% 
  mutate(across(qty_A:qty_D, .names = "amount_{gsub('qty_', '', .col)}") * across(price_A:price_D))

#   region qty_A qty_B qty_C qty_D price_A price_B price_C price_D amount_A amount_B amount_C amount_D
# 1    R_1     1     4     7     7     100     300     170      73      100     1200     1190      511
# 2    R_2     2     1     1     1     110     100     116      11      220      100      116       11
# 3    R_3     3     3     6     6     300     230      66      15      900      690      396       90
```

Comment: A bit of description would be nicer.